# Are faithful algebraic representations closed?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, $G$ a group scheme of finite type over $k$, and $f:G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ a faithful representation. Is $f$ necessarily closed in the Zariski topology? This seems plausible but not obvious.

I ask because I am reading through [Milne's notes on Shimura varieties](https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/svi.pdf). A few proofs (e.g. 1.18) appear to rely on the following unstated, slightly weaker claim: let $G$ be a group scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ a faithful representation. Then $f$ is closed on $\mathbb{R}$-points in the analytic topology. Algebraicity is essential here, e.g. transcendental representations of $\mathbb{R}$ include things like an irrational diagonal on a torus.

Comment: Yes, algebraic subgroups of algebraic groups (meaning group schemes of finite type over a field) are closed in the Zariski topology See, for example, Milne, Algebraic Groups, 1.41

Comment: @jsm I only assume $G$ is a subfunctor of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$, and this does not obviously imply anything as down-to-earth as being a locally closed subscheme.

Comment: A homomorphism of algebraic groups is a monomorphism if and only if it is a closed immersion. See, for example, Milne, Algebraic Groups, 5.34. A homomorphism is a monomorphism if and only if it is injective on $R$-points (all $R$). Ibid. 5.31.